# Is that Luke's T-shirt Claire gave Danny to wear?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist

In Iron Fist S01E11, Claire Temple gave Danny Rand a used T-shirt to wear which had holes. I imagined it to be Luke's shirt but it was not too loose. Is it really Luke's T-shirt or it can be of Daredevil?

[image]

Is there any evidence of it in the show? Claire even said "better then you" to Danny for the status of shirt owner but Luke is supposed to be in Jail for the crime he didn't commit and I don't even remember Matt Murdock wearing any such T-shirt.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a gunshot on his shoulder. Should be easy to track down if Luke was ever hit there.

Comment: My bets are on Daredevil. The size looks like it was his.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the hole in the shoulder is intended to be a *bullet hole* then the only hero we see get shot in that location is Daredevil in Season 2 Ep.13.

[image]

Since Claire references "would-be crime-fighters showing up hurt" and running out her supplies, immediately before giving him the shirt, a reference to Daredevil (after Season 2) would seem the most logical.

Of course it's possible that she's referring to someone else we haven't heard of yet...but I doubt it. The shirt would have been under the Daredevil costume.

Luke *was* shot in the shoulder but **on the other side** and the shirt he was wearing was long-sleeved.

Comment: Nice answer and I should have added the screenshot of t-shirt myself but forgot :)

Comment: Claire uses the plural _"agro would-be crime fighters"_, so I'm not sure why you think that comment is only a reference to Daredevil. - Claire also says about the shirt _"It's clean ... cleaner"_ which seem to suggest that she hasn't washed it. Daredevil bleeds, Luke Cage doesn't. - And since Luke basically made bullet holes a fashion item, it would be odd if a shirt with a bullet hole is _not_ a reference to that.

Comment: *"It's clean ... cleaner"* just means it's cleaner than before...I'd say that means she *has* washed it. If it is intended to be a reference to Luke then we'd need to have seen him hit by a bullet in that shoulder and, as far as I know, we don't. If you can find that...it would be basis of a good alternative answer.

Comment: If it's washed, then saying _"It's clean"_ is enough, I see no reason to add _"...cleaner"_ after a short pause. Which is why I interpreted that as _"...at least cleaner than blood stained shirt you were wearing"_. - I wouldn't be surprised if the producers just didn't bother to check continuity. "Bullet holes in clothes" was a running joke in Luke Cage, so it would be a strange choice to now use a bullet hole in a shirt to reference Daredevil.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen lots of references to Luke Cage wearing bullet-hole shirts. I am pretty sure it is Luke Cage Claire was referencing. Let's not read too much into it. Probably a little lazy with the continuity. Luke wore shabby T-shirts and has been shot more times that most people can keep track of.

Answer (score -3):

It was probably punisher's.
Even though claire was on that show doesn't mean it could be punisher's.